# Compare elements of arrays using for-loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays :

```
A1=[num1,num2,num3]

B1=[digit1,digit2,digit3]
```

I want to create a function that :

gets `digit1`, `digit2` and `digit3` and compares them with `A1 elements`  and do the following:

```
if(digit1>num1)
//draw next page

else if(digit1<num1)
//go to previous page

else if(digit1==num1)
//go and check "digit2" with "num2"

if(digit2>num2)
//draw next frame

else if(digit2<num2)
//remove the latest frame added

else if(digit2==num2)
//got check "digit3" with "num3"

if(digit3>num3)
//draw a div

else if(digit3<num3)
//remove the previous div added

else if(digit3==num3)
//some statement
```

Is there any way I can avoid all this "if-else" and implement this using perhaps a for loop?

Comment: What is `//some statement`? The same everywhere?

Comment: Are those statements all different?

Comment: I don't see any reason for a loop if those statements are all different and do not follow a certain scheme. Or can you generalize them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Notulysses answer is already a good start, you could enhance your logic like this:

```
var dialogs = [  // an indexed Array of the dialogs

    {  // first dialog
        num: 0,
        digit: 0,
        greaterFun: function () {
            // statement if greater than
        },
        lowerFun: function () {
            // statement if lower than
        },
        equalityFun: function () {
            // statement when this.num === this.digit
        }
    }

    /*, {  // second dialog
        num: 1,
        digit: 1,
        greaterFun: function () {
            // statement if greater than
        },
        lowerFun: function () {
            // statement if lower than
        },
        equalityFun: function () {
            // statement when this.num === this.digit
        }
    } */

];
```

Usage

```
for (var i = 0; i < dialogs.length; i++) {
    var dialog = dialogs[i];

    if (dialog.digit > dialog.num) {
        dialog.greaterFun();
    }
    else if (dialog.digit < dialog.num) {
        dialog.lowerFun();
    }
    else if (dialog.digit === dialog.num) {
        dialog.equalityFun();
    }
    else {
        // handle an error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( A1.length == B1.length ) {
   for(var i = 0; i < A1.length ; i++) {
     if( A1[i] > B1[i] )
       //some statement
     else if( A1[i] < B1[i] )
       //some statement
     else if( A1[i] == B1[i] )
       //some statement
   }
}
```

Comment: `for..in` loops are a bad way of iterating arrays.